# can someone help me resolve this issue-The WS-Federation passive protocol endpoint and the SAML protocol endpoint cannot both be null

Tags: saml, adfs

The WS-Federation passive protocol endpoint and the SAML protocol endpoint cannot both be null.

I am the Identity provider and the SAML connection keeps giving me the above error when I try to test it.

Answer (score 0):

In the ADFS wizard under the "Endpoints" tab, have you configured any endpoints?

Did you configure it via metadata or manually?

Did you enable support for SAML?

Have a look at these [screenshots](https://kasmweb.com/docs/latest/guide/saml/adfs.html).